# write definition file with extendable class

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to describe some interface in definition file:

```
declare namespace Foo{
    export interface Bar{
        new(attrs, options)
    }
}
```

and then extend some class from it in my code:

```
class Chunk extends Foo.Bar {}
```

but got error - `error TS2507: Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.`

What is wrong here? How should I describe extendable class in definition file?

Answer (score 0):

Change the interface to a class:

```
declare namespace Foo {
    export class Bar {
        constructor(attrs, options);
    }
}
```